# How can i add information about users instruction into my datatbase using sqlite?

Tags: android, mysql

I am new to `mysql` and `android`,and i am working with the app in which after login successfully user will give instructions, for example if he wants to order pizza but he wants slice with addon, and some special instructions etc.I have made user instruction table where all instruction will be added according to user demand.Now i dont know how can i connect it to the user ..i mean how can admin comes to know who has send the instructions.my logic here about user account is below ...kindly help.
I have made `Tables` like

```
1.Userinfo(to store user info)
2.User Instruction
```

How to store the data so that admin can identify that who has given the instructions?

Comment: In userinfo table you can make a column to save the user instructions that he/she has selected for ex : comma seprated id's of selected instrcution's, id's you can get from instruction's table.

Comment: but there is instruction like small or medium then quantity, crust or adds on, special instruction , there are  4 instruction ...

Comment: So there must be some id for those instructions.You can add id's comma seprated in column.

Comment: yes thr shud be ..can u give example fr tht

Comment: as to how tht will run through query